# Bootstrap-ui dropdown hidden with surrounding div overflow

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a nav bar header with various items on a right alignment. I have set the overflow to hidden on the surrounding div (Toolbox) so that if the screen size changes the header hides under the left hand brand div.

On the nav bar I have placed a bootstrap-ui dropdown. When it is clicked and shown it is cut off by the overflow of the Toolbox div. If I remove the overflow it shows fine, but then i have the issue where the overflow will be seen on a reduced screen size.

How do you enable the drop down to be shown whilst keeping any nav bar content hidden if shrunk?

[plunkre](http://plnkr.co/edit/VJA6h2OvTgLn2H6Rkx6l?p=preview)

```
<div id="ToolBox">
    Some really important text that shouldn't wrap with a reduced width screen
    <span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        Period:{{currentPeriod.Description}}
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="periodSelector" ng-model="currentPeriod" ng-repeat="period in periodList track by period.PeriodId">
            {{period.Description}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>

    <div id="SiteTitle" class="ng-binding">myApp</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Please be more precise. Do you want to hide the dropdown on reduced screen size?

Comment: How do I prevent the drop down from being hidden/cut off by the surrounding div whilst maintaining the overflow (if possible)  ? Better?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use overflow hidden.  It's not doing anything anyway as your toolbox and brand are positioned absolutely.  Using z-index will position one above or below.  What is it that you want to happen on smaller devices?  You can use media queries to restyle your entire toolbar for smaller devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the dropdown-append-to-body attribute should fix the problem. See the documentation [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown) for details.

***edit***

Updated plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/A9PLNTlnFGGCeeOGmD8W?p=preview)

```
<span class="dropdown" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
```

Comment: I tried adding it to the above plunker and no luck I'm afraid. Unless I am doing it wrong!

Comment: Believe it or not, I did actually try the dropdown-append-to-body attribute and it didn't work for me. I noticed that your Plunker was using v0.13 of ui-bootstrap and I was only using v0.12 . When I upgraded it worked fine. It however also requires a later version of Angular, so I'm going to be spending some time checking for breaking changes.... Thanks for the help!